# how can we call multiple php pages in one php page?

Tags: php, call

I have 4 php pages for different purposes, they are as follows:

`readxmlfile.php` : is ued to read data from "result.xml" file and insert data into "ci_result" table. After inserting data into "ci_result" table, the data is below:

```
id     result_list
1      Name = Ciclo-Attivo@Application solutions = @Softwares = @Application solutions = Portale-Ciclo-Attivo$ 1 3$ Ciclo-Attivo$ Portale-Ciclo-Attivo@map level = 0@CI Type = Business Process@                                          
2      Name = Portale-Ciclo-Attivo@Application solutions = @Softwares = @CIs = Fatturazione$ 3 4$ Portale-Ciclo-Attivo$ FatturazionedArco-Portal$ 3 6$ Portale-Ciclo-Attivo$ dArco-PortalMYLFRAdmin SR-CTH3G01$ 3 9$ Portale-Ciclo-Attivo$ MYLFRAdmin SR-CTH3G01@Impact analysis: configuration of the redundancy = The solution is up if all CIs are up@map level = 1@CI Type = Application Solution@
```

and so on...

`loaddataintomaptable.php` : is used to read the data from "ci_result" table and insert into "map_node" and "map_edge"table.

`update_map_tables.php` : is uesed to update the records in the "map_node" and "map_edge" table.

`generate_bp_conf.php`: is used to generate "bp.conf" file after updating "map_node" and "map_edge" tables.

The 4 php pages work properly when I "run" the pages one by one on web server. Now I want to call the 4 php pages in one php page to reduce the additional steps. does any one know how to call multiple pages in one php page ? exactly, can we do "http://localhost/web/pages/readxmlfile.php" for these 4 pages in one php page ?

Comment: Can't you just [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) them?

Comment: I want to know : can we "http://localhost/web/pages/readxmlfile.php " do  multiple pages in one php page ?

Comment: @AnwarAhmad yes it will, use include('yourphpfile.php'); in your file to include all pages (you have to include all of them)

Comment: You have to understand your project business flow. Adding all your scripts inside a single one is something usable for you? You need to call every object, function and variables from those other pages from a single one? If yes, them include them all, or include them into a single "loader" file, and include that loader into the page you want.

Comment: Because this part "*The 4 php pages work properly when I "run" the pages one by one on web server.*" is not clear **at all**. How does them run? One call the other one? A page opens a file and redirects it to another? Are they called separatelly? Manually? As part of a process, or service? You need to clarify your background.

Comment: @AlanMachado , I did manually in order as : "http://localhost/web/pages/readxmlfile.php" ,"
http://localhost/web/pages/loaddataintomaptable.php" ,"http://localhost/web/pages/update_map_tables.php" and "http://localhost/web/pages/generate_bp_conf.php"

Comment: You just "open" them? Like that, opening those links and that's it? No parameter passed, no file selected, no field to fill... just like that?

Comment: @AlanMachado yes, now I just "open" them . But, I want to include these 4 pages in one php page.

Comment: I'm not sure if serial `includes` will solve your issue. Seems like you need a routine that calls each php file when one's done executing. Try to use `include('file.php');` at the end of each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php
include 'readxmlfile.php';
include 'loaddataintomaptable.php';
include 'update_map_tables.php';
include 'generate_bp_conf.php';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create an index.php file and actually you can do this:

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
include_once 'layout.php';
```

And in layout.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
....
<body>
<?php include $page.'.php'; ?>
```

Comment: @Crecket What do you mean by insecure?

Comment: What if someone were to open this page with your example test.com?page=.htaccess%00  This is a nullbyte injection and would include the .htaccess file in that directory

Comment: [Here](https://websec.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/exploiting-php-file-inclusion-overview/) is a example off possible ways people could abuse this. In general, **never** include files based on what a user has entered directly

Comment: @Crecket well, I don't know, this doesn't work on my server. I tried to include the .htaccess with this url: index.php?page=.htaccess%00. Sorry, no full url as it's a non public intranet. I get this error: `Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'pages/.htaccess' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /srv/bav/buildNumber221-appVersion940-coreVersion4064/bav-portal/web/auction-interface/layout.php on line 44` But my file is there...

Comment: Check the site I added in my second comment. I only gave %00 as an example, that specific trick doesn't work everywhere but there are plenty of other ways to abuse your code